# React : _open_weather_map.default.fetchForcast is not a function

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-native

I'm learning React-native to make a App and got some problem in my code.

> _open_weather_map.default.fetchForecast is not a function. (In '_open_weather_map.default.fetchForecast(zip)', '_open_weather_map.default.fetchForecast'is undefined)

I'm working on React-native version 0.59.2, android.

and this is the open_weather_map.js code

```
function zipUrl(zip){
    return '${API_STEM}q=${zip}&units=imperial&APPID=${WETHER_API_KEY}';
}

function fetchForcast(zip){
    return fetch(zipUrl(zip))
        .then(Response=>Response.json())
        .then(responseJSON => {
            return {
                main: responseJSON.weather[0].main,
                description: responseJSON.weather[0].description,
                temp: responseJSON.main.temp
            };
        });
}
```

Comment: You have fetchForecast spelled wrong in your code, so it's not going to see the function.

Comment: @jimboweb Thanks! I fixed it but it still happens :(

Comment: @jimboweb Fixed it! I just forgot to put some other codes in the file! Thanks again!